# How to fix Connection execute error using ADO in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, ado, execute

I'm using ado to connect SQL Server in my C++ project.

So I want to insert/update my database and I wrote some queries (see the code) and I'm trying to execute my connection or command.

But it goes on an error at `pConnection->Execute(InsertQuery, NULL, adCmdUnspecified);`, it says `Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location` and in the debug window there is _hr with value `_hr : DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND One or more errors occurred during processing of command. TYPE: HRESULT`

I also tried to execute Command, but I have the same result as Connection.

Should I change adCmdUnspecified into something or am I go wrong somewhere? 
What is the solution? Thank you in advance.

```
//connections above
VARIANT vNameStringType;

_bstr_t InsertQuery(L"Insert Into TestTB(AccountID, Name) Values(@AccountID, @Name)");

hr = pCommand.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));

pCommand->ActiveConnection = pConnection;
pCommand->CommandText = InsertQuery;
pCommand->CommandType = adCmdText;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    a[i].name;
    a[i].login;

    vIntegerType.vt = VT_I4;
    vIntegerType.intVal = a[i].login;
    vNameStringType.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vNameStringType.bstrVal = _bstr_t(a[i].name);

    int DataExistCounter = 0;       

    NameParam = pCommand->CreateParameter(_bstr_t("@Name"), adVarChar, adParamInput, 150, _bstr_t(vNameStringType));
    pCommand->Parameters->Append(NameParam);
    AccIDParam = pCommand->CreateParameter("@AccountID", adInteger, adParamInput, sizeof(int), vIntegerType);
    pCommand->Parameters->Append(AccIDParam);
    pRecordset->MoveFirst();
    while (!pRecordset->EndOfFile)
    {
        valFieldNam = pRecordset->Fields->GetItem("Name")->Value;
        valFieldAcc = pRecordset->Fields->GetItem("AccountID")->Value;
        if (valFieldAcc == a[i].login)
        {
            DataExistCounter++;
        }
        pRecordset->MoveNext();
    }

    if (DataExistCounter > 0)
    {
        //update    
    }
    else
    {
        pConnection->Execute(InsertQuery, NULL, adCmdUnspecified);
    }
}
pRecordset->Close();
pConnection->Close();
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: What other error messages do you get?  I don't know ADO in C++, but I would be **very** surprised if there were no other messages to go with the one that you posted here.

Comment: i dont have any other error except of this

Comment: If there's truly no other error message then this is the first time in my ~20 years of programming where ADO's "one or more errors occurred" message was not accompanied by other error messages.  How have you confirmed that your `pConnection` object is valid and connected?

Comment: im using connection string which i made by ODBC but if i use full name of connection string there it doesn't work `("Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=...\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True")`
here is my Connection and there is no error

`_bstr_t strCon("ADOSQL");
hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
hr = pConnection->Open(strCon, "", "", adConnectUnspecified);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
   printf("Error Opening Database object using ADO _ConnectionPtr n");
  }`

Comment: but also when i launch my project there is not error but in the debug window nothing is changing to pConnection it shows `<Information not available, no symbols loaded for msado15.dll>'

Comment: this might be reason for error?

Comment: Possibly - as I said, I've never used ADO with C++.  I'm just asking the questions that occur to me in the hopes that the answers might shed some light.

Comment: thank you that question maybe helps me